# Angular 7: Disable button after click, and prevent it from enabling after page refresh

Tags: html, angular7

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="button" *ngIf="this.isButtonVisible" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger"
            [disabled]="isPunchInDisable" (click)="punchInTime()">
            <span class="btn-label"></span>Punch In</button> &nbsp;
        <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger"
            [disabled]="isPunchOutDisable" (click)="punchOutTime()">
            <span class="btn-label"></span>Punch Out</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to disable a punchIn button after clicking? Also, it has to remain disabled after refreshing page.

Answer (score 0):

- For that you need to make use of some persistence layer like localstorage or DataBase.
  Better to use Database to store the punchIn status.
- So whenever you click on **Punch In** just save that status to DB and for any app load/reload just get that status from DB and then based on that disable or enable the button.

So the flag **isPunchInDisable** should set based on the status you get from DB.

if your requirement is just specific to one browser, then you can make use of **local storage** to store the status. But be aware , if user clears his browser localstorage , the data will go off.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
          <div class="media-body">
                <button type="button" [disabled]="punchIn_Time" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger" (click)="punchInTime()">
                <span class="btn-label"></span>Punch In</button> &nbsp;
                <button type="button" *ngIf="punchIn_Time" [disabled]="punchOut_Time" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger" (click)="punchOutTime()">
                <span class="btn-label"></span>Punch Out</button>
            </div>
```